# pspdfkit_flutter: Programmatically Navigate to page

Tags: flutter, dart, pspdfkit

How to enable navigation between preceding and subsequent pages through the button action within a Floating widget(which has next and previous buttons):

```dart
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FloatingDraggableWidget(
            mainScreenWidget:
                PspdfkitWidget(documentPath: documentPath, key: pspdfkitKey),
            floatingWidget: const FloatingControlPanel(),
            floatingWidgetWidth: 180,
            floatingWidgetHeight: 50,
      ),
    );
```